# How to define an explicit binding with maven configuration : Coordinates

Tags: java, sql, jooq

When i'm generating java classes from jooq generator, i get one field deprecated :

```java
/**
 * @deprecated Unknown data type. Please define an explicit {@link org.jooq.Binding} to specify how this type should be handled. Deprecation can be turned off using <deprecationOnUnknownTypes/> in your code generator configuration.
 */
@java.lang.Deprecated
public final TableField<PositionRecord, Object> COORDINATES = createField("coordinates", org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.getDefaultDataType("point"), this, "");
```

I am not sure to know how to define the binding on my maven configuration with the "Point" type.

Any ideas ?

Edit :

```xml
<configuration>

    <!-- JDBC connection parameters -->
    <jdbc>
        <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
        <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/${jooq.generation.schema}</url>
        <user>${jooq.generation.user}</user>
        <password>${jooq.generation.password}</password>
    </jdbc>

    <!-- Generator parameters -->
    <generator>
        <generate>
            <javaTimeTypes>true</javaTimeTypes>
        </generate>
        <database>
            <name>org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDatabase</name>
            <includes>.*</includes>
            <dateAsTimestamp>true</dateAsTimestamp>

            <!-- In case your database supports catalogs, e.g. SQL Server:
            <inputCatalog>public</inputCatalog>
              -->
            <inputSchema>${jooq.generation.schema}</inputSchema>
        </database>
        <target>
            <packageName>${jooq.generation.package}</packageName>
            <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
        </target>
    </generator>
</configuration>
```

So far i've been able to use my java classes generated by this configuration. But some fields are deprecated because of some "Data type" not recognized. So i've found out that we could kinda use "force type" and put it in the maven configuration + adding the corresponding binding to let know jooq about this data type. For instance in our case : we want to be able to reach the field "Coordinates" ( as a Point type in java). I hope i was clear enough.

Comment: If you want people to help you, you should be more specific: what you want to achieve, what is your current configuration, what are the generated Java classes from, etc? Unfortunately a lot of SO community members are arrogant enough to just downvote your post without any explanation - most probably this insufficient description was the reason why someone downvoted it. We cannot read your mind, please specify your problem.

Comment: *"So i've found out that we could kinda use "force type" and put it in the maven configuration + adding the corresponding binding to let know jooq about this data type"* - That's the correct way, you need to use a data type binding: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings. What are you struggling with *in particular*?

Answer (score 0):

You've already answered your question:

> So i've found out that we could kinda use "force type" and put it in the maven configuration + adding the corresponding binding to let know jooq about this data type

That's the correct way, you need to use a data type binding: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings

Follow the instructions from the manual and you'll be fine.